# how to show pop up or custom toast in onStop() or onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have an app how to make some notification when reaching specific time ...
I would to show some pop-up or custom layout when my app is `onStop` or `onDestroy`.
I would like this photo.

[image]
*(click to enlarge)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a Toast (easy and immediate). More complex way is that you've to grant 2 special permissions "draw over other apps" and "app with usage access" (which are special permissions, so you need to create your own page to prompt the user to grant it), after which you can add your custom view directly to the windows manager of the system. Last but not least, you should seriously think if there's any benefit for the user to be notified on main screen about something **after** your main page has been stopped or destroyed, because that goes against the system design quite a lot.

Comment: thanks sir .. but duration of toast is Shortly ..Is there a way to prolong the duration

Comment: Yes you can pass the duration to makeText()

Comment: how can do that ?

Comment: ? :? did you actually read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) or the source code? Note: duration is either LENGTH_LONG or LENGTH_SHORT.

Comment: Ok let's face it: what do you have to say to the user, and why? Please give context, then I tell you if you need to go the hard way or not :) because remember the user is leaving your app, to go to do something else, so you can't really hook it up for 10s because she wants to go to read news or whatever.

Comment: Pity you haven't answered my last question :) if you need help shout but my instructions should be enough to get you started

Comment: i would make an application who tell the user some beautiful words every 1 hours

Comment: @MaamounMedOussama but then why only for onStop() and onDestroy()?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to give a message then `Toast` is enough and easy.

```
    @override
    public void onStop() {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Your message here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Your message here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**EDIT**: I won't recommend you to write long messages in `Toast` and show it for longer durations, instead consider a [Statusbar Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications). Status Bar Notifications can be programmatically canceled when they are no longer relevant.

**BUT** If you still want to increase the duration of Toast message then here is a workaround.

```
private Toast mToastToShow;
public void showToast(View view) {
   // Set the toast and duration
   int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;
   mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world, I am a toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

   // Set the countdown to display the toast
   CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
   toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 1000 /*Tick duration*/) {
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mToastToShow.show();
      }
      public void onFinish() {
         mToastToShow.cancel();
         }
   };

   // Show the toast and starts the countdown
   mToastToShow.show();
   toastCountDown.start();
}
```

**Here is how it works:** the countdown has a notification time shorter than the duration for which the toast is displayed according to the flag, so the toast can be shown again if the countdown is not finished. If the toast is shown again while it is still on screen, it will stay there for the whole duration without blinking. When the countdown is finished, the toast is canceled to hide it even if its display duration is not over.

Comment: thanks sir .. but duration of toast is Shortly ..Is there a way to prolong the duration

Comment: @MaamounMedOussama how long do you want to display it?

Comment: `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` display for 2 secs and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` display for 3.5 secs

Comment: i want 10s for the user read all the content before disappear it